# SQL - Update a table using LAG and based on another column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a dashboard with python and dash/plotly that receives inputs from the user and then run a query on Google BigQuery.

One of the queries updates a column (PAY_FT), uses other column (PAY_CLEAN) and a string input from the dashboard.

```
    DECLARE cpi STRING DEFAULT "C";
    UPDATE `xx.yy.zz` t
    SET
    PAY_FT = s.PAY_FT
    FROM
    (
    SELECT
        RN,
        CASE
        WHEN RN = 1 AND cpi = "S" AND PAY_SHALE_COR = "PAY" THEN 1
        WHEN RN = 1 AND cpi = "C" AND PAY_CLEAN = "PAY" THEN 1
        WHEN RN = 1 THEN 0
        WHEN RN > 1 AND cpi = "S" AND PAY_SHALE_COR = "PAY" THEN 0.2 + (LAG(PAY_FT, 1) OVER(ORDER BY RN))
        WHEN RN > 1 AND cpi = "C" AND PAY_CLEAN = "PAY" THEN 0.2 + (LAG(PAY_FT, 1) OVER(ORDER BY RN))
        ELSE (LAG(PAY_FT, 1) OVER(ORDER BY RN))
        END
        AS PAY_FT
    FROM
        `xx.yy.zz`
    WHERE
        DEPTH_M IS NOT NULL
    )
    s
    WHERE
    t.RN = s.RN
```

But it's not working as intended. This query returns the following:

[image]

It works until DEPTH_M = 102.2, but after that it dows not return the 0.4 from the previous row. So, for example, if we had a "PAY" in DEPTH_M = 103.2, until 103.0 should return 0.4 and in 103.2 it should be 0.6.

How can I fix it?

Here's a sample of my data: [SAMPLE.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AuVv-bcMzYWjArWJXqpYh-3Ogf6iTOzJ/view?usp=sharing)

My desired outpu should be:

| DEPTH_M | PAY_CLEAN | PAY_FT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101.2 | PAY | 0.2 |
| 101.4 | PAY | 0.4 |
| 101.6 | - | 0.4 |
| 101.8 | - | 0.4 |
| 102.0 | - | 0.4 |
| 102.2 | - | 0.4 |
| 102.4 | - | 0.4 |
| 102.6 | - | 0.4 |
| 102.8 | - | 0.4 |
| 103.0 | - | 0.4 |
| 103.2 | - | 0.4 |
| 103.4 | - | 0.4 |

Let's say that we got another PAY on another row, the output should be:

| DEPTH_M | PAY_CLEAN | PAY_FT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101.2 | PAY | 0.2 |
| 101.4 | PAY | 0.4 |
| 101.6 | - | 0.4 |
| 101.8 | - | 0.4 |
| 102.0 | - | 0.4 |
| 102.2 | - | 0.4 |
| 102.4 | - | 0.4 |
| 102.6 | - | 0.4 |
| 102.8 | - | 0.4 |
| 103.0 | PAY | 0.6 |
| 103.2 | - | 0.6 |
| 103.4 | - | 0.6 |

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post your original table structure and some sample data so that it can help us figuring out if conditions are culprit?

Comment: @khan I edited my post to include a csv with sample data.

Comment: Could you please ellaborate a little bit more, and specify the expected output? I am still not sure about what you need to solve here.

Comment: @daniellidio show us your desired output

Comment: @daniellidio wait , PAY_FT  is a new column you are making or its an existing column ? you have that column in your sample data and you are making a new column with the same name.

Comment: nevertheless I'm able to get values for produced "PAY_FT" up to DEPTH_M 103.0 by using your query and your sample data

Comment: @eshirvana PAY_FT its an existing column. I have the table already created, so I'm updating the values (which originally were 0). I updated my question with my desired output.

Comment: @ACC I edited my question with my desired output

Comment: @daniellidio, so by LAG(PAY_FT) , you want the NEW UPDATED value of previous pay_ft, is that correct ? if yes , its not as simple as you think ,  you would need recursive cte

Comment: @eshirvana yes, it would be the new updated value of previous PAY_FT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the second thought you can go with this query which is much simpler and does what you want and you don't need to check for RN :

```
SELECT RN
    ,0.2 * COUNT(CASE WHEN (cpi = "S" AND PAY_SHALE_COR = "PAY") 
              OR (cpi = "C" AND PAY_CLEAN = "PAY") THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY RN) 
 + SUM(CASE WHEN RN = 1 AND ((cpi = "S" AND PAY_SHALE_COR = "PAY") 
   OR (cpi = "C" AND PAY_CLEAN = "PAY")) THEN 0.8 ELSE 0 end) OVER () NEW_Pay_FT
FROM `xx.yy.zz`
WHERE DEPTH_M IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I incorporated your query on mine to use as an update and it worked!